# Ubuntu installation does not start

Tags: usb, system-installation, hardware

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my old laptop (Celeron 1.7, 1Mb RAM) from a CD/DVD. I downloaded an older distribution with no PAE (I have already tried 9.04 and 10.4).

Both downloads freeze when I start the very first step of the installation - when I click on Install Ubuntu /Install Ubuntu desktop (whatever is after the language selection) - installation just freezes with dash/underscore on the screen.
I have already done the checksum for both downloads (they are ok), performed the memory test (it is also ok). Disk check freezes the system too, but I dbl checked the hdd on another Ubuntu pc and it returned no errors. Installation also freezes at the same stage when I completely remove hdd...

What could possibly be wrong and any solution to this?

Thanks!

---

Yes, thank you the memory is  1Gb!

Comment: Was it a typo that you have 1Mb RAM?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, note that to answer your own question, do not add your answer by editing your question, but just answer in the field "**Your Answer**", and then you can mark your own answer as **"Accepted"** to let other people identify which answer solved your problem (refer to [this help](http://askubuntu.com/tour))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem - both distros were conflicting with a new usb hub I used to connect the keyboard and the mouse to the notebook. This one - [http://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Port-USB-power-adapter/dp/B00DQFGJR4/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1402920652&sr=8-2&keywords=usb+hub+powered+amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DQFGJR4)